# What could cause initialization order to corrupt the stack?

Tags: c++, stack-corruption

Question is in bold below :

This works fine:

```
void process_batch( 
  string_vector & v
) 
{

  training_entry te;
  entry_vector sv; 
  assert(sv.size() == 0);
...
}
```

However, this causes the assert to fail :

```
   void process_batch( 
      string_vector & v
    ) 
    {
      entry_vector sv; 
      training_entry te;
      assert(sv.size() == 0);
      ...
   }
```

Now I know this issue isn't shrink wrapped, so I'll restrict my question to this: **what conditions could cause such a problem ? Specifically: variable initialization getting damaged dependant on appearance order in the stack frame. There are no malloc's or free's in my code, and no unsafe functions like strcpy, memcpy etc... it's modern c++. Compilers used: gcc and clang.**

For brevity here are the type's

```
struct line_string
{
  boost::uint32_t line_no;
  std::string     line;
};

typedef  std::vector<boost::uint32_t> line_vector;
typedef std::vector<line_vector> entry_vector;
typedef std::vector<line_string> string_vector;

struct training_body
{
  boost::uint32_t url_id;
  bool relevant;
};

struct training_entry
{
  boost::uint32_t session_id;
  boost::uint32_t region_id;
  std::vector< training_body> urls;
};
```

p.s., I am in no way saying that there is a issue in the compiler, it's probably my code. But since I am templatizing some code I wrote a long time ago, the issue has me completely stumped, I don't know where to look to find the problem.

**edit**

followed nim's suggestion and went through the following loop

1. shrink wrap the code to what I have shown here, compile and test, no problem.
2. `#if 0` `#endif` to shrink wrap the main program.
3. remove headers till it compiles in shrink wrapped form.
4. remove library links till compiles in shrink wrapped form.

Solution: removing link to protocol buffers gets rid of the problem

Comment: The code you've shown is OK, and could not reasonably cause the `assert` to fail. But, the existence of that `assert` makes me think that you aren't showing us something. `sv.size` must be zero. Why compare it to 100? Is there something else in the declaration list?

Comment: Question updated , I also reran the code as well with the updated assert. Same results.

Comment: Hassan, you may have missed my point. I *know* `assert(sv.size==0)` will fail. I'm saying, if the original author compared the size to 100, he must not have default-constructed the vector. From this I infer that there is some other declaration than what you are showing.

Comment: naive way to detect what's happening (given it's not your full code), comment out all the declarations bar the vector, then uncomment line-by-line till you get the error, the last type is the one causing the problem - investigate that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual case for this when one of the created objects writes beyond
its end in the constructor.  And the most frequent reason this happens
in code I've seen is that object files have been compiled with different
versions of the header; e.g. at some point in time, you added (or
removed) a data member of one of the classes, and didn't recompile all
of the files which use it.

Comment: In a separate comment OP says, "I picked up a new version of gcc today." The classes in question are all `std::` classes, so getting a new library may explain it.

Comment: Hassan, can you do the equivalent of `make clean` or `rm *.o` and then rebuild? Also, can you confirm with certainty that your standard C++ includes are *precisely* the same version as your C++ libraries?

Comment: @Rob That sounds likely.  I'd guess that his makefile doesn't manage dependencies on the system library.  Whenever you update one of your external tools, it's best to do a `make clean`.  Especially when that tool is the compiler.

Comment: recompile wasn't fixing it. However, shrink wrapping the main code and getting rid of protocol buffer link did fix the problem. So I guess I need to recompile protocol buffers. I'm moving back to debian ! I still don't get how protocol buffers cause this problem, the stack entry in question did not have any pbuf code in it. I suspect pbuf is pulling in some old libc or stl code in. I am using the static version of the protobuf library. I don't understand the exact nature of the problem though.

Comment: Your code uses instantiations of some templates.  It's possible that the protocol buffer code uses the same templates, and that the link was picking up its instantiation for things like the constructor, rather than yours.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard guarantees that the following assertion will succeed:

```
std::vector<anything> Default; 
//in your case anything is line_vector and Default is sv
assert(Default.size() == 0);
```

So, either you're not telling the whole story or you have a broken STL implementation.

**OR:** You have **undefined behavior** in your code. The C++ standard gives **no guarantees** about the behavior of a program which has a construct leading to UB, **even prior to reaching that construct.**

Comment: I'm thinking that the stl or boost might be broken, I am using arch linux on this machine, and I picked up a new version of gcc today. I expect arch wouldn't push such system-breaking updates to users ?. However the problem shows up with clang as well.

Answer (score 1):

What *might* cause the sort of problem you see is a user-defined type with a misbehaving constructor;

```
class BrokenType {
  public:
  int i;
  BrokenType() { this[1].i = 9999; } // Bug!
};

void process_batch( 
  string_vector & v
) 
{

  training_entry te;
  BrokenType b;  // bug in BrokenType shows up as assert fail in std::vector
  entry_vector sv; 
  assert(sv.size() < 100);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the right version of the Boost libaries suited for your platform? (64 bit/32 bit)? I'm asking since the entry_vector object seems to be have a couple of member variables of type boost::uint32_t. I'm not sure what could be the behaviour if your executable is built for one platform and the boost library loaded is of another platform.